# Delete object in array by parent id recursively

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm working on recursive methods.

'The array' has 'objects' which have parentId and Id for itself.

I wanna make a function: when I choose one object, wanna delete every child object by parentId. also at the same time child's child should be deleted.

Now this code works on some child objects, but not for all. and I don't know why does it not working.

Could you please help me to figure out this problem?

```
    function deleteMindMap(obj) {


        alert('Before Delete : ' + JSON.stringify(savedArray));

        savedArray = deleteUsingParentId(savedArray, obj.id);           

        alert('After Delete : ' + JSON.stringify(savedArray));

        //Rewriting to firebase
        mindRef.remove();
        writeMindMap(savedArray);



    }
```

---

```
function deleteUsingParentId(data, parentId) {
    var updatedArray = savedArray.filter((item) => {

    return item.parent !=  parentId;

    })

    return updatedArray;
}
```

---

tried the code but still not working on parent object and child's child object.

this is the result of the code when I deleted the object of id '12'

cause '123', '1234' have parent id '12',

'123456789 1234567890' , '12345, 123456' should be deleted

cause they are child of '123' and '1234'

and also '12' is not deleted.

```
Before Delete : [
{"afterX":485,"afterY":271,"id":"1","kind":"line","parent":"1","x":448,"y":220},
{"afterX":643,"afterY":276,"id":"12","kind":"line","parent":"1","x":490,"y":278},
{"afterX":732,"afterY":238,"id":"123","kind":"line","parent":"12","x":659,"y":283},{"afterX":708,"afterY":413,"id":"1234","kind":"line","parent":"12","x":668,"y":291},
{"afterX":847,"afterY":390,"id":"12345","kind":"line","parent":"1234","x":721,"y":418},
{"afterX":791,"afterY":494,"id":"123456","kind":"line","parent":"1234","x":715,"y":427},
{"afterX":904,"afterY":520,"id":"1234567","kind":"line","parent":"123456","x":810,"y":503},
{"afterX":944,"afterY":301,"id":"12345678","kind":"line","parent":"1234567","x":913,"y":521},
{"afterX":796,"afterY":136,"id":"123456789","kind":"line","parent":"123","x":736,"y":230},
{"afterX":869,"afterY":227,"id":"1234567890","kind":"line","parent":"123","x":752,"y":245}]


After Delete : [{"afterX":485,"afterY":271,"id":"1","kind":"line","parent":"1","x":448,"y":220},
{"afterX":643,"afterY":276,"id":"12","kind":"line","parent":"1","x":490,"y":278},
{"afterX":847,"afterY":390,"id":"12345","kind":"line","parent":"1234","x":721,"y":418},
{"afterX":791,"afterY":494,"id":"123456","kind":"line","parent":"1234","x":715,"y":427},
{"afterX":904,"afterY":520,"id":"1234567","kind":"line","parent":"123456","x":810,"y":503},
{"afterX":944,"afterY":301,"id":"12345678","kind":"line","parent":"1234567","x":913,"y":521},
{"afterX":796,"afterY":136,"id":"123456789","kind":"line","parent":"123","x":736,"y":230},
{"afterX":869,"afterY":227,"id":"1234567890","kind":"line","parent":"123","x":752,"y":245}
]
```

Comment: Please share sample structure of `savedArray`

Comment: You can share the input array and expected out put array as well, will help to understand the algorithm you are try to implement much better

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55114632/edit). The comments are not the place for data

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited

Comment: you can filter your item from the existing data. use the `array.filter` method.

Comment: Please update after and before object with `It cannot delete child's child` scenario

Comment: @Dipak now I added some informations for the scenario.

Comment: With the updated data, 12 is the ID used to remove items?

Comment: @Dipak Id number '12'. when I click one point, I get the closest object by using location calculating function. the object has those fields that I posted. That result happened when I clicked the object comes with '12' id.

Comment: Just want to be more clear on this scenario, sorry for my lack of understanding. So this is what I am understanding now:

When we pass and Id to delete we have to
1.   delete all the elements with that Id as parent property value  
2.  delete all the items based on the id of deleted items, which is used as parent Id.

is that correct?

Comment: @Dipak 2. if other object(child)  have the deleted id as parent property, It should also be deleted. like when you delete one mindmap, every child map should be deleted, and also the child map's child should be deleted as well.

Comment: @Dipak that's why I tried to use recursive method to delete child's child, but failed to solve this problem. do you need the previous code that I posted?

Comment: No, let me try it out again. Got your actual requirement now.

Comment: @Dipak thank you. I'll try myself again, too.

Comment: @HOEINN I edited my answer, I think it should do what you're looking for

Comment: @HOEINN When you accept an answer, always mark it with the checkmark under the upvote/downvote buttons to credit the answer

Comment: @Axel thanks for your comment again. first time got answer from stackoverflow so didn't aware of it. I marked the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you're looking for. It may break if you have circular dependencies. It still uses recursion but I moved the recursion inside the `filter` function.

```
function deleteChild(id){
    function filter(_target){
        let toDelete = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < savedArray.length; i++){
            if(savedArray[i].id == _target || savedArray[i].parent == _target){
                toDelete.push(i);
                if(savedArray[i].id != _target){
                    toDelete = toDelete.concat(filter(savedArray[i].id).slice(1));
                }
            }
        }

        return toDelete;
    }
    const targets = filter(id).sort();
    for(let i = targets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        savedArray.splice(targets[i],1);
    }
}
```

In your example you omitted `1234567` and `12345678` who should also get deleted. `1234567` is a child of `123456`, who got deleted and `12345678` is a child of `1234567`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I followed Dipak's solution, but still not working. now updated additional informations and I'll appreciated it if you could help me out.

Comment: I tried this code, and this is what I wanted. Thank you for your kindness. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @HOEINN if this code is what you want don't forget to mark it as an answer with the green check mark

Comment: Can I ask for the reason of slice(1) when you call recursive filter? Everything is understandable but stucked in that code

Comment: Again, Can you tell me the reason of slice(1) when you call recursive filter?

Comment: @HOEINN remove it and see what changes. If you rework the recursive function you may not need it

Comment: What I understood is that the slice method is only effective when the savedArray is sorted by id number. Cause the slice(1) removes (0) and that (0) has the same id number of parent coming from next reculsive func. But the prob is the array is not sorted. So it was not perfectly working. Anyway I figured it out! thks

Answer (score 2):

So this is my understanding about the problem:

- Remove all the items in the given array based on the parent property value.
- While removing each item make sure to remove the items having same parent property value of the removed item's id.

```js
var savedArray = [
 {
  afterX: 485,
  afterY: 271,
  id: "1",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "1",
  x: 448,
  y: 220
 },
 {
  afterX: 643,
  afterY: 276,
  id: "12",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "1",
  x: 490,
  y: 278
 },
 {
  afterX: 732,
  afterY: 238,
  id: "123",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "12",
  x: 659,
  y: 283
 },
 {
  afterX: 708,
  afterY: 413,
  id: "1234",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "12",
  x: 668,
  y: 291
 },
 {
  afterX: 847,
  afterY: 390,
  id: "12345",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "1234",
  x: 721,
  y: 418
 },
 {
  afterX: 791,
  afterY: 494,
  id: "123456",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "1234",
  x: 715,
  y: 427
 },
 {
  afterX: 904,
  afterY: 520,
  id: "1234567",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "123456",
  x: 810,
  y: 503
 },
 {
  afterX: 944,
  afterY: 301,
  id: "12345678",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "1234567",
  x: 913,
  y: 521
 },
 {
  afterX: 796,
  afterY: 136,
  id: "123456789",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "123",
  x: 736,
  y: 230
 },
 {
  afterX: 869,
  afterY: 227,
  id: "1234567890",
  kind: "line",
  parent: "123",
  x: 752,
  y: 245
 }
];

function removeByIds(arr, parentIdsToBeRemoved) {
 // if there is no parentIdsToBeRemoved return whole array
 if (!parentIdsToBeRemoved || parentIdsToBeRemoved.length == 0) {
  return arr;
 }
 var tempIdsToBeRemoved = [];
 var newArr = arr.filter((item, index) => {
  if (parentIdsToBeRemoved.indexOf(item.parent) > -1) {
   tempIdsToBeRemoved.push(item.id);
  } else {
   return item;
  }
 });
 return removeByIds(newArr, tempIdsToBeRemoved);
}


function removeById(arr, id) {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    return item.id != id;
  })
}

var output = removeByIds(savedArray, ["12"]);
output = removeById(output, "12");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is the parameter of data?

Comment: `savedArray` , its called like this in the bottom : `deleteUsingParentId(savedArray, 12)`

Comment: I tried on my project, but this code sometimes can't delete the initial parent. also It cannot delete child's child problem!

Comment: updated my question - you can check the before and result of the method

Comment: What is that scenario of child's child? Please share the sample `saveArray` and output with that scenario as well. And initial parent means first item in the array right?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet with the sample data provided, and by passing the id `123` initial items getting removed also. Try to use the return object from `deleteUsingParentId` function in your code for further processing.

Comment: @HOE INN Can you please show us some input and expected output by editing your question

Comment: Now I tried few times and added some additional informations on my question! Also added array objects before and after the method. but still have same problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer as well, used the latest data you provided. And you can I have passed `12` as the parent Id which needed to be removed. And the result is exactly matching with the after object you have shared.

Comment: @Dipak after object should not be matching with my posting. 
''
this is the result of the code when I deleted the object of id '12'

cause '123', '1234' have parent id '12',

'123456789 1234567890' , '12345, 123456' should be deleted

cause they are child of '123' and '1234'

and also '12' is not deleted. ''

Comment: Let me try this code after dinner! Thx again I'll check it in 2 hours!

Comment: @Dipak I just checked it! every child is deleted perfectly, only problem is that the parentId is not deleted. like when I put '12', the object with '12' is not deleted. The answer below solved this problem. Again, thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @HOEINN I have updated the answer to remove the item with id also. Added as a new function. We have to call that function using the output of the first function. Please do mark the answer as accepted one if this resolved your problem.

Comment: Want to mark your answer but the other guy answered first so I marked his first. Sorry for answering now and thank you again